# How do I do an Oracle SQL update from select in a specific order?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table with old values (some null) and new values for various attributes, all inserted at different add times throughout the months. I'm trying to update a second table with records with business month end dates. Right now, these records only contain the most recent new values for all month end dates. The goal is to create historical data by updating the previous month end values with the old values from the first table. I am a beginner and was able to come up with a query to update on one object where there was one entry from the first table. Now I am trying to expand the query to include multiple objects, with possible, multiple old values within the same month. I tried to use "order by" (since I need to make updates for a month in ascending order so it gets the latest value) but read that doesn't work with update statements without a subquery.  So I tried my hand at making a more complicated query, without success. I am getting the following error: single-row subquery returns more than one row. Thanks!

TableA:

```
| ID | TYPE | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE | ADD_TIME|
-----------------------------------------------
| 1 | A     | 2 | 3 | 1/11/2019 8:00:00am |
| 1 | B     | 3 | 4 | 12/10/2018 8:00:00am|
| 1 | B     | 4 | 5 | 12/11/2018 8:00:00am|
| 2 | A     | 5 | 1 | 12/5/2018 08:00:00am|
| 2 | A     | 1 | 2 | 12/5/2019 09:00:00am|
| 2 | A     | 2 | 3 | 12/5/2019 10:00:00am|
| 2 | B     | 1 | 2 | 12/5/2019 10:00:00am|
```

TableB

```
| ID | MONTH_END | TYPE_A | TYPE_B | 
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 1/31/19  | 3  | 5 |
| 1  | 12/31/18 | 3  | 5 |
| 1  | 11/30/18 | 3  | 5 |
| 2  | 12/31/18 | 3  | 2 |
| 2  | 11/30/18 | 3  | 2 |
```

Desired Output for TableB

```
| ID | MONTH_END | TYPE_A | TYPE_B | 
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 1/31/19  | 3  | 5 |
| 1  | 12/31/18 | 2  | 5 |
| 1  | 11/30/18 | 2  | 3 |
| 2  | 12/31/18 | 3  | 2 |
| 2  | 11/30/18 | 5  | 2 |
```

My Query for Type A (Which I plan to adapt for Type B and execute as well for the desired output)

```
update TableB B
set b.type_a =
(
    with aa as
    (
    select id, nvl(old_value, new_value) typea, add_time
    from TableA 
    where type = 'A'
    order by id, add_time ascending
    )
select typea
from aa
where aa.id = b.id
and b.month_end <= aa.add_tm
)
where exists
(
    with aa as
    (
    select id, nvl(old_value, new_value) typea, add_time
    from TableA 
    where type = 'A'
    order by id, add_time ascending
    )
select typea
from aa
where aa.id = b.id
and b.month_end <= aa.add_tm
)
```

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural one, so the order in which things happen isn't relevant. In fact, it's important that it doesn't do that. It's good that you included data, but I can't figure out how you're getting from your existing output to your desired output. Can you restate the rules involved?

Answer (score 0):

Kudo's for giving example input data and desired output. I found your question a bit confusing so let me rephrase to "Provide the last type a value from table a that is in the same month as the month end.

By matching on type and date of entry, we can get your answer. The "ROWNUM=1" is to limit result set to a single entry in case there is more than one row with the same add_time. This SQL is still a mess, maybe someone else can come up with a better one.

```
UPDATE tableb b
   SET b.typea   =
           (SELECT old_value
              FROM tablea a
             WHERE     LAST_DAY( TRUNC( a.add_time ) ) = b.month_end
                   AND TYPE = 'A'
                   AND add_time =
                       (SELECT MAX( add_time )
                          FROM tablea
                         WHERE TYPE = 'A' AND LAST_DAY( TRUNC( a.add_time ) ) = b.month_end)
                   AND ROWNUM = 1)
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT old_value
              FROM tablea a
             WHERE LAST_DAY( TRUNC( a.add_time ) ) = b.month_end AND TYPE = 'A');
```